# Strange Count value after calling FileRead

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-10-seattle

I'm trying to compare the number of bytes read with the count passed to [FileRead](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.FileRead) which is a wrapper around the WinAPi [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

The problem is that I get different values based on the structure of my `ReadFromFile` procedure (none of the added/subtracted lines change the count variable).

If you run the below code you get this output

```
FileHandle: 400
SizeOfFile: 8672
Current position: 8655
aCount before SetLength: 17
aCount before FileRead: 17
Number of bytes read: 17
aCount after FileRead: 2200
EAccessViolation: Access violation at address 0040C5BC in module 'Project7.exe'. Read of address C23C30BA
```

the AV is because of freeing the dynamic array by the compiler at the end of scope (this is not always).
as you can see the `count == 2200` here (I got 0 before this) after the FileRead. If you comment out the second API Call or Line two the count is right

Can you tell me what is this and how can I solve it?

```
program Project7;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, WinAPI.Windows, System.Classes;


procedure ReadFromFile(aFileHandle: THandle; aCount: Longint);
var
  aPosition, ReadRes: Int64;
  TmpBuffer: TBytes;
begin
  writeln('aCount before SetLength: ',aCount);
  SetLength(TmpBuffer, aCount);
  writeln('aCount before FileRead: ',aCount);
  ReadRes := FileRead(aFileHandle, TmpBuffer, aCount);
  Writeln('Number of bytes read: ', ReadRes);
  //aPosition := FileSeek(aFileHandle, 0, Ord(soCurrent)); // second API call
  //Writeln('Current position after read: ', aPosition);  // line two
  writeln('aCount after FileRead: ',aCount);
  if ReadRes <> aCount then
    //Raise Exception.Create('hi there');
 // DoWrite(TmpBuffer[0], aCount);
end;

var
  FFileHandle: THandle;
  aFileName: string;
  I1: Integer;
  aFilePhysicalSize: Int64;
  FPosition: Int64;
begin
  try
    aFileName := 'C:\Users\nacereddine\Desktop\ascii-table.gif';
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    FFileHandle := CreateFile(PChar(aFileName), GENERIC_READ,
                                FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING,
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    Writeln('FileHandle: ', FFileHandle);
    aFilePhysicalSize := FileSeek(FFileHandle, 0 , Ord(soEnd));
    Writeln('SizeOfFile: ', aFilePhysicalSize);
    FPosition := FileSeek(FFileHandle, aFilePhysicalSize - 17 , Ord(soBeginning));
    Writeln('Current position: ', FPosition);
    I1 := 17;
    ReadFromFile(FFileHandle, I1);

    readln;

  except

    on E: Exception do
    begin
    Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    readln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using version of procedure `fileread` with untyped second parameter here:

```
TmpBuffer: TBytes;
...
ReadRes := FileRead(aFileHandle, TmpBuffer, aCount);
```

but in this case you should dereference dynamic array like `TmpBuffer[0]`

From your help link:

```
 //this version is used
 function FileRead(Handle: THandle; var Buffer; Count: LongWord): Integer;
 //perhaps you wanted that one:
 function FileRead(Handle: THandle; var Buffer: TBytes; Offset, Count: LongWord): Integer;
```

Comment: ahh the untyped parameters. I hate those. the function is now working fine. however can I describe what I had as undefined behavior or what. the last os error was 0 and the function succeeded.

Comment: OS call can work without os error- handle is valid, address belongs to your memory space and so on... You just write into unexpected memory (AV might occur later)